# How to keep main array as original

Tags: javascript

```
var masterData= main;

var fData = masterData.graphs;

var legendname  = somename ;                
var filteredData = fData.filter(function (d){
    console.log(d);
    if(d.name.toLowerCase() == legendName.toLowerCase()){
        return d.name.toLowerCase() != legendName.toLowerCase();
    }

    return d;
});

MainData = filteredData;

console.log(MainData);
console.log(masterData);
```

It is working fine, but my masterdata also gets filtered. I want to keep masterdata always original. Please suggest

Comment: `filter` returns a new array, it doesn't modify the original.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/boedsmk0/1/

Comment: It is basically inside a customized js that is handling D3 chart plotting ,i have added some demo code here,i will cross check my code again,thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`var masterData = $.extend(true, {}, main)`

To deep copy the data if it can be

Comment: Since `filter` makes a new array, why do you need to make a deep copy? And did you forget to finish your sentence? `if it can be` what?

Comment: thanks ,this has done the tricks and also had some issues in my code .

Comment: Deep copy the data if it can be deep copied is what that sentence means

Answer (score 0):

If your masterData.graphs; is an array. 
By  doing var fData = masterData.graphs; It will copy masterData.graphs reference to fdata.
You can try : `var fData = masterData.graphs.slice();`

Comment: But `filter` creates a new array, so you don't need to make a copy first.